# Laravel generated email not apply fomat HTML

Tags: html, laravel, email

I created email with markdown laravel . I get the email content (HTML) but it not true , My email not received tag HTML .
[Here is my email , thanks a lot of your help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqLYP.png)

I tried
php artisan view:clear ,
php artisan cache:clear ,
php artisan queue:restart but it still not success .

Comment: you pass some variable in mail markdown templete or not if yes then  {!! $variable !!}

Comment: like this @component('mail::message')
{{$subject}}

{!! $emailbody !!}

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Error when create mail blade . Whitespace be made mail not receive "HTML" . After deleted it , Mail was correct  [Email blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04rmj.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).